# How to run play2 web application from Eclipse ( ScalaIDE plugin )

Tags: scala, deployment, playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-ide

I am using Eclipse Juno with Scala plugin. As of now to work with play2 web application I have to first fire terminal and execute `play debug ~run`  ( or `play run` if I don't want to debug ), and then I can work in Eclipse and after each save `play` does it job of deploying the code again to jetty.

Can I somehow skip this terminal step?  I just want to run the web app from Eclipse. For J2EE web application, Eclipse have nice server integration. We can deploy and run the application from Eclipse to tomcat ( or any other server ) easily.  Is there something similar for Play2?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no way to skip this step. I have spent some time looking for this over the last few weeks with no luck. My co-worker, who has been working with play for several months, isn't aware of any tools either.

Comment: This is really strange. 5yrs since Play framework is launched, and even now we don't have complete integration in eclipse.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal If you think in a way, its perfect this way. Because play is sbt based. It is just a set of files unlike java where you build war and that is used by eclipse to deploy. It makes it more matured this way,

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but a slightly more efficient method - I have a windows batch file (for linux, use a script) in my eclipse project that starts the play server - at least you don't have to leave eclipse and hit the command line by hand. No real difference to starting a tomcat server from eclipse for a java war project. This batch also starts chrome browser after waiting for 10s (just enough time for the play server to come up) and points to the server url

the batch file contents - obviously, change your paths...

echo off

cd\eclipse\workspace\testApp

start play run

timeout 10

start chrome http://{server_url}:9000